# Cambiar valor de registro automaticamente en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas("prestamo","cronograma") y en los cuales prestamo tiene el campo "estado" y quisiera saber si se puede cambiar el valor a 1 de ese campo cuando todos los registros del campo estado en mi tabla cronograma es 1
Estas son mis tablas
Esta es mi tabla cronograma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es mi tabla prestamo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo quieres resolver el problema, desde un script en Php por ejemplo o con un sentencia en MySql?

Comment: con una sentencia MySql

Comment: Con un disparador, después de insertar o modificar `cronograma` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar con un UPDATE y una subconsulta, de esta forma

```html
UPDATE test.prestamo p1
SET 
    estado = 1
WHERE
    0 = (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            test.cronograma c
        WHERE
            p1.estado != 1
            AND p1.idprestamo = c.idprestamo
        )
```